# remove reactions after click discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am creating `music bot` using `discord.js` and already created a custom `embed` with `reactions` which can **pause**, **stop** etc. the music.

I would like to make sure that when any user **clicks** on the reaction this is automatically **removed**, I tried to use the `reactionCollector` following the [Guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html) but I was unable to implement it, can you help me out?

This is my code:

```
const { Message } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'setup',
    description: "ruoli con emote",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client, testChannelId) {

        console.log(testChannelId)
        const channel = '831573587579371580';
        const playem = '⏯️';
        const stopem = '⏹️';
        const nextem = '⏭️';
        //const shuffleem = '';
        const loopem = '';
        const volume15 = '';
        const volume30 = '';
        const mute = '';

        
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Nessuna canzone in riproduzione al momento :(')
            .setImage('https://images4.alphacoders.com/943/943845.jpg')
            .addFields(
                {name: 'Rule 1', value: 'figo'},
                {name: 'Rule 2', value: 'hhj'},
                {name: 'Rule 3', value: 'tipo'}
            )    
            .setFooter('il prefisso per questo server è: *');

        console.log('message: ' + message)
        console.log('args: ' + args)
        console.log('Discord: ' + Discord)
        console.log('client: ' + client)
       
        var botname = ' ' // setup messaggio con reazioni
    
        const createdChannel = await message.guild.channels.create(botname, { //Create a channel

            type: 'text', //Make sure the channel is a text channel
            permissionOverwrites: [{ //Set permission overwrites
                id: message.guild.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            }],            

    }).then(createdChannel =>  createdChannel.send(createdChannel.id, embed)).then(function (messageEmbed) {
               
        messageEmbed.react(playem);
        messageEmbed.react(stopem);
        messageEmbed.react(nextem);
        //messageEmbed.react(shuffleem); 
        messageEmbed.react(loopem);
        messageEmbed.react(volume15);
        messageEmbed.react(volume30);
        messageEmbed.react(mute);        
  
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;       
                      
                switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                    
                    case playem:
                        console.log('Pausa / resume');
                        client.commands.get('prova').execute(client, message, args, Discord, createdChannel);
                        break;

                    case stopem:
                        console.log('stop');
                        client.commands.get('stop').execute(client, message, args);
                        break;

                    case nextem:
                        console.log('Skip');
                        client.commands.get('skip').execute(client, message, args);
                        break;

                    case loopem:
                        console.log('loop');
                        client.commands.get('loop').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;

                    case volume15:
                        console.log('volume15');
                        client.commands.get('volume15').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;

                    case volume30:
                        console.log('volume30');
                        client.commands.get('volume30').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;

                    case mute:
                        console.log('muto');
                        client.commands.get('mute').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;
                        

                }            
                
        });

        }). catch(function(){
            console.log('Errore');
        });
        
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this will help people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you would want to use is `reaction.users.remove(user)`. Take a look at the below links. Some of the methods in Discord.Js have changed when Discord.Js v12 came out.

Hopefully, these links help you with what you're trying to do

- Guide: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#removing-reactions-by-user
- Docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager?scrollTo=remove

---

So in your case you would do something like

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;        
    switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
        // CASES IN-BETWEEN.
    }
    reaction.users.remove(user)          
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a specific reaction like this:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (message) => {
   message.reactions.cache.get('484535447171760141').remove()
      .catch(error => console.error('Failed to remove reactions: ', error));
});
```

And if you only want to remove the reactions from a user you should do this:

```
const userReactions = message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(userId));
try {
    for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
        await reaction.users.remove(userId);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to remove reactions.');
}
```

---

### Keep this in mind:

- Your bot needs `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permissions in order to do this!
- > Make sure not to remove reactions by emoji or by user too much; if there are many reactions or users, it can be considered API spam

---

*You can also take a look at the **[Official guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#removing-reactions)***